# Maven build error after setting toolchain right

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-toolchains-plugin

I have Java version 1.8.111 installed and the initial error message after running `mvn3 install` was as below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) on project myfile: Cannot find matching toolchain definitions for the following toolchain types:
[ERROR] jdk [ vendor='sun' version='1.6' ]
[ERROR] Please make sure you define the required toolchains in your ~/.m2/toolchains.xml file.
```

To resolved this, I've updated my toolchains.xml to version 1.8.111 but still getting the same error. I've also tried after running `mvn3 clean` and successfully cleaned but still getting the same error.

Could anyone pinpoint where this version 1.6 is fetched from?
I checked JAVA_HOME already, it's set to 1.8.

Can anyone explain how maven calls Java version?

Appreciate your help.

Below is my toolchains.xml
[image]

Comment: I believe that your are interpreting the error message in the wrong way. To me it seems that the project you are trying to build requires a JDK 1.6.x to build. To test for this you could edit your toolchains.xml to tell maven to use your JDK 1.8 as a toolchain for JDK 1.6

Comment: Can you post your `~/.m2/toolchains.xml` file?

Comment: How should it be interpreted? Could you explain what that error message is saying?

Answer (score 25):

Your application is expected to be built with `JDK 1.6` and to locate it Maven is looking for definition of `[ vendor='sun' version='1.6' ]` within `toolchains.xml` in your `{home}/.m2/` directory (see eg [this maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)). You just need to point to it and all should be good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
       <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.X_XX.jdk/Contents/Home</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

Comment: works flawlessly for jdk9 as well...just replace <version>1.6</version> with <version>9</version>

Comment: There is a typo in your encoding attribute: the correct value is `UTF-8`, not `UTF8`.